# Sort pandas Series both on values and index

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, series, numpy-ndarray

I want to sort a Series in descending by value but also I need to respect the alphabetical order of the index.
Suppose the Series is like this:

```
(index)
a         2
b         5
d         3
z         1
t         1
g         2
n         3
l         6
f         6
f         7
```

I need to convert it to the following Series without converting to DataFrame and then convert it to Series,

out:

```
(index)
f         7
f         6
l         6
b         5
d         3
n         3
a         2
g         2
t         1
z         1
```

I used `lexsort` but It wasn't suitable. It sorts both the value and index in ascending.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: do not use images of data/code I rolled back to text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first sort the index, then sort the values with a stable algorithm:

```
s.sort_index().sort_values(ascending=False, kind='stable')
```

output:

```
f    7
l    6
b    5
d    3
n    3
a    2
g    2
t    1
z    1
dtype: int64
```

used input:

```
s = pd.Series({'a': 2, 'b': 5, 'd': 3, 'z': 1, 't': 1, 'g': 2, 'n': 3, 'l': 6, 'f': 7})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Series.sort_values(axis=0, ascending=False)
```

Can you try if this works given the information you have provided.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find the code solution:

```
y = s.nlargest(n)
```

n: the number of the largest values to return.